# Update Record Code Error

Tags: sql-server

I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a ComboBox to a String.

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click

    If txtBursaryR_ID.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Id")
    Else
        Dim DBcon As SqlConnection

        DBcon = New SqlConnection("Server=.\FGG;Database=CAOOSC_DB;User=sa;Pwd=c0nstella;")

        Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_Beneficiaries Set BursaryR_ID=@BursaryR_ID,Donor_ID=@Donor_ID,DonorName=@DonorName,Province=@Province,District=@District,First_Name=@First_Name,Last_Name=@Last_Name,Sex=@Sex,Name_of_School=@Name_of_School,School_Address=@School_Address,Grade_Enrolled=@Grade_Enrolled,Prev_School=@Prev_School,Prev_District=@Prev_District,Intake_Year=@Intake_Year,Child_Vulnerability=@Child_Vulnerability,Children_Disabled=@Children_Disabled,Bursary_Provided=@Bursary_Provided,Supplies=@Supplies,GFirst_Name=@GFirst_Name,GLast_Name=@GLast_Name,Contact_Number=@Contact_Number, ", DBcon)

        command.Parameters.Add("@Donor_ID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtDonor_ID
        command.Parameters.Add("@DonorName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbDonorName.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Province", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbProvince.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@District", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbDistrict.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@First_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirst_Name
        command.Parameters.Add("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLast_Name
        command.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cbSex.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name_of_School", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName_of_School
        command.Parameters.Add("@School_Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress
        command.Parameters.Add("@Grade_Enrolled", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtGrade_Enrolled
        command.Parameters.Add("@Prev_School", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPre_School
        command.Parameters.Add("@Prev_District", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPrev_District.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Intake_Year", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cbIntake_Year.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Child_Vulnerability", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbChild_Vulnerability.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Children_Disabled", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbChildren_Disabled.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Bursary_Provided", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cbBursary_Provided.SelectedItem
        command.Parameters.Add("@Supplies", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSupplies
        command.Parameters.Add("@GFirst_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtGFirst_Name
        command.Parameters.Add("@GLast_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtGLast_Name
        command.Parameters.Add("@Contact_Number", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtGContact

        DBcon.Open()

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data Not Updated")
        End If

        DBcon.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What came up when you copy/pasted that error into Google?

Comment: `cbXxx.selecteditem.ToString()`  are any of the values null?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: it looks like your setting your avalues for your combo boxes to the .SelectedItem, I believe that is an object, you need to use .SelectedItem.value  or .tostring

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say your code is probably trying to set the values of your parameters to objects, when what you want is to set them to the text-values in those objects.

For example, in the first one, this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Donor_ID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtDonor_ID
```

Should probably be something more like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Donor_ID", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtDonor_ID.Text
```

And so on.

Comment: and its probably a good idea for validation purposes to maybe put the values into a string and set the value in your SQL to the string value.  So you can check if the values are blank/null first before passing to your SQL paramaters.

Comment: @Brad thanks for your response. I think the system is now checking the values after putting the values tostring however I am now getting a different error which is breaking my code indicating that the values are null even when there are values in all the text boxes and combos on after the form loads. Apparently I have two buttons on the form one which searches for the data in my SQL DB and displays the values on the form and the other where I have placed the update code to enable me to edit the data and update. How do I fix it?

Comment: @BrightonIlukena sorry, that's an entirely different question, and should be posted as such.   From the part of the code you've posted, there's no way to tell why the values are null.

Answer (score 0):

I guess cbSex.SelectedItem is ComboBox.SelectedItem type object.To get the string value from ComboBox.SelectedItem you should have to use SelectedItem.Text or SelectedValue. also If txtDonor_ID is TextBox type variable then you should have to use txtDonor_ID.Text. follow this for all other Control.

```
txtDonor_ID.Text
cbSex.SelectedItem.Text or  cbSex.SelectedValue
```

Comment: This might be the correct answer but could you please explain it so that it's clear what the problem was?

Comment: cbSex.SelectedItem.Text for getting display text and cbSex.SelectedValue for getting inner value.

Comment: @MoinulIslam thanks a lot for the solution. I have managed to fix the problem and it seems the error is fixed however another error now is popping up ("An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CAOOSC_APP.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") How do I fix this

Comment: It's very difficult to say which object is null. please read exception details and error throw line. I think this helps you to dig down.